# Mathematics needed for higher dimensional category theory?

Tags: higher-category-theory, soft-question

I'm a undergrad(third year, Manchester uni and want to do a PhD) that is thinking of doing a PhD in this area or category theory in general.(Sorry for asking it here, Maths exchange stack didn't help as asked twice last week and then today, I spend like an hour a day worrying about what I'm studying and what I should study). Imagine a chess board and you need to move a piece, how you know you are moving the best piece?, now times that by a thousand.

Just wondering, what branches of Maths should I focus on? As I've been told that topology particular Algebraic topology is the main area for this. A lecturer told me I should focus on getting down Algebraic topology before thinking of doing category theory as most of the examples of category theory are from algebraic topology.

However, another lecturer told me I should be doing logic and particular model theory. I can take a course in it this year, but would mean not doing commutative algebra.

So before you delete this can you please tell me what I should be studying? As it would save me countless hours of worrying if I'm doing the right subjects.

P.S. I can do most of the stuff in Conceptual Mathematics category book. I don't understand topoi through.

Comment: So you've asked two professors, in-person, and gotten two different answers.  And now you've come to ask thousands of virtual mathematicians...

Comment: Well, I agree with that. However, I've asked about four different Mathematician. Each giving me drastically different answer. Like a topologist was telling me you have to study algebraic geometry. I doubt I can get more confused. Just want to get told study x and then everyone agreeing with it. 

Comment: I don't think mathematics works like that. There's no way you're going to get anywhere by learning only the bare minimum necessary for your particular field, if such a thing even exists. This is why you're getting such different answers. You're going to have to learn about all of those things to some extent, but probably you will only be able to learn one or two of them in-depth. (There's no point in deciding which ones now.) 

Comment: @ Dan: Thanks for that. I suppose it's a bit backwards, but I don't have natural talent for Maths. So I like to know what I should study so I don't waste my time studying stuff I don't need. I know I can learn algebra in-depth. However, can't get a straight answer and one lecturer just told me to focus on getting grades, another just told me I can't possibly know what I'm going to study this early.  

Comment: @simplicity - it depends if you want to do Lurie/Joyal/Rezk-style higher category theory, namely quasi-categories aka $(\infty,1)$-categories, or traditional higher category theory (e.g. Leinster's book or the Australian school). If you are planning on doing a PhD you should not just rely on what you learn in courses. Read around! Expose yourself to as much maths as you can.

Comment: @ David. Thanks for the advice. I have looked at mainly at Eugenia Cheng higher dimensional categories book. So it be more of Leinster stuff. On exposing myself to more Maths. I'm trying to avoid that. Certainly, do I need to know analysis? and functional analysis. Don't really want to learn analysis. Just want to narrow my focus

Comment: @simplicity - what do you want to do with this hypothetical PhD of yours? Research or otherwise? If you are looking at higher category theory, I would guess the former, and in that case, one needs to at least absorb the 'vibe' of as much maths as you can. If you don't _really love_ maths, then you may underestimate how much a PhD demands of you.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if higher category theory is really the theme of so much of this new Century mathematics or if category theorists have just done a wide advertisement of their field on the internet... (or perhaps both...)

Comment: Please do not cross-post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65559/mathematics-needed-for-higher-dimensional-category-theory

Comment: @ David. I suppose you are right in that sense. I will try and learn main branches of Maths i.e. Algebra, topology, analysis and logic. I am planning to learn Algebraic Geometry and learn some Physics. Well, I plan to become a Mathematician, so do a PhD then travel for a through years. On love maths, I'm actually sacrificing a lot of social life for Maths plus I doubt I will have children or a family when I'm older. 

@ Unknowngoogle. Yeah, n-category cafe made it seem very interesting. Plus I read a book on Grothendieck as a teenager. 

Comment: @Yuan. Sorry for cross-posting.

Comment: It is my impression that some clarification is needed which is tried to achieve in the comments. However, it seems better to me if this clarification is worked out and then the question addressed. So, I vote to close now (but would likely vote to reopen a clarified version). [Note: the question is close to closure and this comment thread is growing a bit complex. Perhaps a meta could be useful; but I did not follow this closelt enough to know so I did not create one.]
 

Comment: Dear Simplicity999, It will never happen that you will be told unanimously to study some particular *x* and be done with it.  This would be true with regard to any area of mathematics, but all the more so with higher category theory, which is one of the more abstract and recent parts of math, which hence draws on a very broad range of motivations and inspirations.   In general, the advice that you are given by any particular mathematician will reflect that person's point of view and predilections.  Since different people have different view points and different predilections, ... . Regards, 

Comment: You should definitely NOT take model theory instead of commutative algebra! The edifice of model theory used by the working mathematician is much, much smaller, and much easier to learn, than a working mathematician's commutative algebra. Commutative algebra has intuitions (coming from Algebraic Geometry) that build over the span of years, and it is best to get started quickly. You can always learn basic model theory later from a book.

Answer (score 21):

It seems to me that category theory (whether higher or not) may be the worst part of mathematics to approach with a narrow viewpoint --- just topology, or just algebraic geometry, or just logic, or just any one area.  To me, much of the value and beauty of category theory lies in how it exhibits connections and similarities among many areas of mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

As many other have just said you cannot think to study just some particular subjects ignoring some other areas, expecially if you want to do research. 
Most of math was born from the observation of some similar phenomena in many different areas: for instance the concept of category itself was born from the observation that in math we deal every time with collections of structures and morphisms preserving those structures, that led to the abstraction of category, similarly I strongly doubt that Grothendieck could invent the concept of (generalized) sheaf if first he hadn't known the many concrete sheaves that appear in topology, differential geometry and algebraic geometry, so it couldn't get to the concept of (Grothendieck's) topos, and without that I'm not so sure that Lawvere could get to the concept of elementary topos while doing his research in logic. This are just some example of as math have evolved thanks to interaction of different areas (for instance, as you can see in the example above, from interaction of  geometry and logic).

Just to answer to your comment about analysis there's a professor in Italy who studies higher dimensional category theory for his research in analysis, so analysis need higher category theory.

Of course the best place where you can get a lot of intuition of higher category theory is algebraic topology where higher categories are used to model homotopy types for topological spaces, via $\infty$-groupoids, and directed space, via $(n,r)$-categories where $n,r \in \omega \cup \{\infty\}$ but you can find a lot of higher dimensional category theory in logic and computer science too, I've seen some application in calculability theory and model theory where (higher) category theory is used to model the semantic of theories, in particular type theory  (if you're interested in application of higher categorical logic-model theory you can take a look to Makkai's work and also Mike Shulman's work on homotopy type theory). Also in mathematical physics there are a lot of higher category theory as John Baez's work prove.

I suppose above you were referring to Cheng-Lauda "Illustrated guide book", that's a good book if you want to learn many approaches to $n$-categories, but in higher category theory there's a lot of more then just $(n,r)$-categories (like usually Mr.Shulman says), Leinster's "Higher operads, Higher categories" is more complete from this point of view because it presents a lot of stuff like generalized multicategories/operads or $fc$-multicategories. Anyway if you want some references on higher category theory you can find some [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69251/is-mac-lane-still-the-best-place-to-learn-category-theory/69266#69266).

Hope this may help you.

(Edit: I've improved a little the answer now that I've found some other references.)

Comment: It is strange as I was under the strong impression that you specialize and only focus on one area of Maths(unless your name is Conway or Tao). Like the idea that a algebraist doesn't need to know analysis. Yeah, I've been trying to look into Baez work and learning the Physics around it. Thanks for the reference. 

Comment: simplicity999, the idea that an algebraic doesn't need to know analysis is wrong. First of all, in graduate school you likely will need to pass some qualifying exams that involve algebra, analysis and geometry.  Second of all, major areas of algebra (e.g.,representation theory, number theory) get some inspiration from ideas in analysis. Other areas of algebra might not, but Blass is right in his answer that it's ironic someone with the intention of working in category theory would anticipate having a limited range of mathematical interests.

Comment: @KConrad - assuming the student is in the US. For better or worse, not all countries have qual exams.

Comment: I think you're confusing the fact that most mathematicians only do research in one area, with the idea that mathematicians don't know the basics of other subjects.  When you're talking about math at the upper undergrad level or first year graduate student level, that's stuff everyone is supposed to know (though, of course, many of us have forgotten parts of it).  Specialization begins in earnest after a year or two of graduate school.

Comment: Dear Simplicity999, You impression about specialization may partly reflect your experience in the UK, where the time to complete a PhD is less than in the U.S. or (I believe) other European countries, so that students are forced to specialize early.  But math is a highly interconnected subject, and it is not just the famous prize-winners who have a broad point of view.  In the UK, my impression is that it is often the immediate post-PhD years in which people try to broaden their focus (e.g. by taking a post-doc abroad).    Regards, Matthew


Comment: David: Oops! Indeed I should've reread the start of the question more carefully. In any event, I still stand by my "second of all" rationale for why simplicity999 shouldn't automatically presume that whatever area he may someday specialize in would not benefit from a basic understanding of other areas.

Comment: Dear Noah, Remember that in the U.K. PhD students have only three (or maybe 3.5) years from beginning to end, so it is more essential to immediately specialize than in the U.S., just for the sake of getting out the other end with a finished thesis.   But I agree with your general sentiment.  And of course, the *arguments* in any particular theorem may use methods from all over mathematics, even if the goal is to prove a result about one particular area.  Best wishes, Matthew 

Comment: Good point.  Though I thought this was partly because in the UK you're expected to have learned the equivalent of a first-year grad curriculum in the US while you were still an undergrad.

Comment: Just a small note: According to this link Leray introduced sheaves, http://jeff560.tripod.com/s.html

Comment: @Eivind I think that it refers to first time the word sheaf was used, while Grothendieck was the actual one who generalized to more abstract context. By the way I'll do a research about this, thanks to the tips.

Comment: For people interested in an overview on European higher-eduction systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process   


Comment: Dear Giorgio, Eivind is correct that Leray invented sheaves.  They were then used by Oka and Cartan in several complex variables, and by Serre in algebraic geometry, before being taken up by Grothendieck as one of his main toosl.  Of course, he greatly generalized the notion of sheaf, by generalizing the notion of topology to Grothendieck topologies, sites, topoi, etc.  Regards, Matthew